In the Quran does it talk about whether Lazarus rose from his grave by prophet Esa before he ascended to heaven or after?
Christians believe that Jesus did this to Lazarus after 3 days in his tomb, when did prophet Esa do this according to the Quran? If he did so?
Could you please answer with references to Quranic verses.

According to the present Gospel, Jesus resurrected Lazarus before his own crucifixion and ascent to heaven. See John 11.

The apparent wording of the Quran would also suggest the same. Read through verses 3:49-55.
